# findFirst() on SortedSet.stream()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The java 8 API doc for `SortedSet` only states that `stream()` is inherited from `java.util.Collection` (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html). This implies that the stream is sequential but may not be ordered.

So what is the safest way to ensure that `sortedSet.stream().filter(...).findFirst()` behaves equally to a classic `for( ... )` loop returning the first matching element? Or is that already the case but just not guaranteed be the API?

(`findFirst()` api doc: *If the stream has no encounter order, then any element may be returned.*)

`Stream.sorted()` should do the trick, but this adds the overhead of sorting elements which are already sorted in the original set.

Comment: `SortedSet.stream().sorted()` doesn't sort the stream because it is already sorted

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov: that’s only possible, when the `SortedSet` is sorted according to the same order as the Stream’s `sorted` request. The current implementation exploits this even less, only skipping the sorting when the `SortedSet` has a `null` comparator and the `sorted()` request without a comparator has been used. If a comparator has been supplied, it doesn’t check whether specified comparators are identical and it doesn’t consider that `null` and `Comparator.naturalOrder()` are semantically the same.

Comment: @Holger Right. So, it is better not to use `sorted()` at all in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right, `SortedSet` inherits `stream()` javadoc from `Collection`, but what you should really look is `spliterator()` javadoc. This is an excerpt:

> The `{@code Spliterator}` reports `{@link Spliterator#DISTINCT}`,
>   `{@link Spliterator#SORTED}` and `{@link Spliterator#ORDERED}`.

Note the `Spliterator.SORTED` characteristic. This means that every implementation of `SortedSet` must return a sorted stream. So, `sortedSet.stream().findFirst()` always returns the lowest element.

Answer (score 6):

`SortedSet` has a defined encounter order, and `findFirst()` is guaranteed to return the first element in the encounter order, if the stream has one.  So the spec already tells you what you want -- you don't need to do anything special.

BTW, `sortedSet.stream().sorted()` will get optimized away (since the `Spliterator` returned from `sortedSet.stream()` will have the `SORTED` characteristic), so doing this doesn't actually incur the cost of sorting -- but you still don't need to do it.

Comment: Having the `SORTED` characteristic is not sufficient for skipping the `sorted` request; it also has to be the same order. Afaik, the current implementation only skips the sorting when the `SortedSet` has a `null` comparator and the `sorted()` request without a comparator has been used. If a comparator has been supplied, it doesn’t check whether specified comparators are identical and it doesn’t consider that `null` and `Comparator.naturalOrder()` are semantically the same. And as far as I could see, the devs consider removing that single special case rather than adding handling of more cases.

Comment: So the statement should be “`sortedSet.stream().sorted()` will get optimized away, if the `sortedSet` has a `null` comparator, but you shouldn’t rely on it”…